# Help with a function I found in a VB.NET 2.0 app I am maintaining

Tags: vb.net

I was going through some reports that were supposed to be displaying 2/1/2009 - 2/28/2009, but instead was displaying 2/1/2009 - 3/1/2009. I have narrowed the bug down to this code, any suggestions?

```
Function GetMonthLastDate(ByVal sDateTime As DateTime)
    Try
        Dim strArrMonth() As String = {"", "31", "29", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"}
        Dim days As Integer
        If sDateTime.Month = 2 Then
            If sDateTime.Year Mod 400 = 0 Then Return sDateTime.AddDays(28)
            If sDateTime.Year Mod 100 = 0 Then Return sDateTime.AddDays(27)
            If sDateTime.Year Mod 4 = 0 Then Return sDateTime.AddDays(28)
        End If
        days = strArrMonth(sDateTime.Month)
        Return Format(sDateTime.AddDays(days - 1), "MM/dd/yyyy")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("<script>alert('" & ex.Message & "');</script>")
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: WOW... thats a WTF all right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is some seriously convoluted code for what it's doing. You can accomplish the same thing like this:

```
Function GetMonthLastDate(ByVal sDateTime As DateTime)
  Dim nextMonth As DateTime = sDateTime.AddMonths(1)
  Return New DateTime(nextMonth.YearPart, nextMonth.MonthPart, 1).AddDays(-1)
End Function
```

That might be a little cryptic, but it should work and can be expanded for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx)?  It makes the code *much* more clear.

```
Function GetMonthLastDate(ByVal srcDate As DateTime) As String
    return _
       new DateTime(srcDate.Year, srcDate.Month, _
                    DateTime.DaysInMonth(srcDate.Year, srcDate.Month)) _
           .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
End Function
```

You could just as easily (and probably ought to) return the DateTime itself (by changing the return type and nixing the `.ToString(...)`), but I see your original function returned it as a formatted string, so for compatibility purposes I've kept it the way you had it.

Comment: Just a note: you can't divide up lines like that in vb, and date is also a type in vb

Comment: @Joel: Good catch.  Darn VB... I guess my C# is showing :| ... anyway, it should be better now.  Thanks again...

Answer (score 6):

In the lookup array, index 2 (valued at 29) is only right for leap years.

That whole function is just bad: it's way over-complicated, returns an incorrect result, doesn't specify the return type, and not only has a type prefix on the parameter name but it's the *wrong* prefix.

Do it like this instead:

```
Function GetLastMonthDate(ByVal dtDateTime As DateTime) As DateTime
    Return dtDateTime.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(dtDateTime.Year, dtDateTime.Month)-dtDateTime.Day)
End Function
```

Beyond this, it appears the original returns a string, which is really not appropriate.  This function should return a DateTime and let the function that calls it handle the appropriate string conversion.

Comment: ha youre right it does return a string in its current form, and the app broke when i returned a datetime. ;p